# WPF TreeView Drag and Drop - Drop event always fires when clicking element

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, treeview

I'm trying to put together a drag & drop solution in WPF TreeView control, using these techniques:
[Dragging and dropping to a TreeView, finding the index where to insert the dropped item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429972/dragging-and-dropping-to-a-treeview-finding-the-index-where-to-insert-the-dropp)

When the user clicks on a TreeViewItem, first the `treeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown` gets executed, then the `treeViewItem_Drop` also. At every single click.

Comment: the `treeViewItem_Drop` event will be raised when the mouse button is released.  Are you calling `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()` from the `treeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown` handler?  If so, try calling it from a `treeViewItem_MouseMove` handler instead.  Just make sure that the left mouse button is pressed before calling `DoDragDrop`.

Comment: Many thanks, this solved it. Can you please post this as an answer and I will mark it as the corret answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're calling `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()` from the `treeViewItem_MouseLeftButton` handler.  The `treeViewItem_Drop` even is raised when the mouse button is released, so you're getting a drop event on every mouse click.  Try calling `DoDragDrop` from a `treeViewItem_MouseMove` handler instead.  Just make sure that the left mouse button is pressed before calling `DroDragDrop`.  You may also want to make sure the mouse has moved a minimum distance before starting the `DragDrop` operation as well, such as

```
if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed 
    && horizontal_move > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance)
{
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop();
}
```